# Unlock tezbox only with Ledger Nano S

Tags: ledger, tezbox

Can I unlock Tezbox main account only with Ledger Nano S? I can't find 15-word phrase or private key. I have already synchronized the main account with Ledger nano S, and I already delegate my tezos. On my Ledger Nano S I see the public key.

Comment: You did not give full details: did you lose your ledger ? Please give more context cause it is unclear your situation.

Comment: I have my ledger.. and 24 words of ledger.. I can't restore the tezbox, because i couldnt find 15 words for unlock or private key.. But on my ledger i can see the public key for account on tezbox, wich is correct on tezbox. So my question is, if i can unloc or restore somehow tezbo with ledger?

Comment: if the public key is indeed protected by the ledger itself then you can import it say with the command line client and manage the funds directly from there.

Comment: I need more instructions how to do that. I can see public key on my ledger, and when i want to link tezbo with ledger, there is displayed the right public key.

Comment: check these instructions from obsidian systems https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/getting-started-with-tezos-on-the-ledger-nano-s-c011517b0f3c

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to _create_ a tezbox wallet using your ledger? Like, the little "Do you want to link a Hardware Wallet? Link your TezBox" link?

Answer (score 2):

If you have lost your seed phrase and your private key you are pretty much screwed

The whole cryptography scheme relies on the fact that only the owner of the seed or private key can access your account, so if there were another way - everything would fall apart

Welcome to crypto

Comment: I think he lost the tezbox passphrase not the ledger passphrase. The ledger passphrase has 24 words.